# wordpress wp-json prefix issue

Tags: rest-api, json

I'm using Wordpress 4.9+ which I believe enabled with REST api by default. My permalinks are set to `Month and Name` And I'm using Foxhound React theme for my site.

Now my rest api should be available in

`http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`

But its available in

`http://example.com/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`

This is why my theme gets 404 error when tries to get data from api.

[image: image error]

Now my question is how do I make my REST available without the `/index.php` prefix

I've manually deployed everything in aws ubuntu micro with a Lamp server. Wordpress files are in the root folder (`/var/www/html/`)

Also I have tried mod_rewrite module using the following steps

```
a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And this is my `.htaccess` file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the permalink structure of your website.

1. Goto **Settings > Permalink**.
2. Remove `index.php` from the *Custom Structure*.
3. Click on `Save Changes`.

It re-generate your permalink structure. And you'll be able to access the posts with `http://example.com/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`

**Updated:**

`.htaccess` code like below:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev.fresh/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /dev.fresh/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**Note: Change `dev.fresh` with your own domain.**

Comment: I've updated the question with my htaccess file. And also i'm not using custom structure permalinks. i'm using month and name. I don't see any prefix except for the domain name in the interface

Comment: First 3 steps worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are may trying to get your url like `http://example.com/...../posts` instead of `http://example.com/index.php/...../posts`

It's the problem of your server. Your server doesn't support that because you're may using `Lightpd` server.

You can edit `rewrite_once` in lightpd.conf if it's lightpd server.
Also, if your server support htaccess you can add this line to rewrite url.

```
"^(.+)/?$" => "/index.php/$1"
```

This is for lightpd and this regex you can use for htaccess.

**Update:** As you've said your server support htaccess, use this code in your htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index.php
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: I have updated the questions with my htaccess file. can you please tell me which line i need to modify. Sorry i'm noob in wordpress

Comment: @FaysalAhmed Does your server support htaccess?

Comment: yes it supports htaccess

Comment: @FaysalAhmed I've updated please check out

Comment: did that replacing with my domain. still dont work

Comment: @FaysalAhmed What's the exception here? Please, be sure if your htaccess is supported on server

Comment: @FaysalAhmed use of "a2enmod" is not enough to use rewrite rules, you need to set `AllowOverride All` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all

Comment: @mmm May be this is his problem